# How to configure paragraphs module for multilingual

Tags: i18n-l10n

I try to configure the [Paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) drupal module for a multilingual website.

I have :

- set the content type translatable with field translation
- enable translation on the paragraphs field
- enable translation for the field in the paragraph bundle (or not)

However, when I create some content and translate it, the existing paragraphs are not displaying in the other language.

What's the correct/working way?

Answer (score 0):

From the community documentation about [Field Translation](https://www.drupal.org/node/1279346):

> Note: The Field Translation module does not provide content translation for fields. This functionality is provided by the [Entity Translation (ET)](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module.

So could it be that the [Entity Translation](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_translation) module is what is missing?

Comment: Entity Translation compatibility with paragraphs is a work in progress. See [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2452675)